# Using Import-SPweb -IncludeUserSecurity slow

Tags: list, powershell, import

I am quite often asked to move lists/document libraries etc. between Sharepoint sites and retain the Author, Modified by data and the like. Now I can do this fine using the -IncludeUserSecurity switch on the Import-SPweb command but unfortunately it is very slow, about half an hour a list regardless of size. Does anyone know of a way to speed this process up? I know it enumerates permissions on the list so is obviously going to be a little slower than not using the switch.

It is a little frustrating having 50 lists to move and having to leave my script running overnight to do what should only take a few minutes. Is there a way of speeding this up or is it something we have to live with?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, when you use includeusersecurity it will export ALL users in that site collection (whether or not they have access to the list or not).  Then when it imports SP has to ensure each one of those users is added to the new site collection (which also included an AD lookup) and fix any user id numbers in the list as part of the import.  So if you have a site collection which is everyone's homepage for instance, then it will have to export and import essentially everyone in your company.

So anyway, I'm not really sure there is anything you can do currently to speed this up other than better planning for the lists you need to export so they are in site collections with smaller groups of people that have access and thus the site collection user list will be smaller.  But obviously, you can't always control that.

Also, I would make sure there is a domain controller closeby to your SharePoint boxes and that it is performing as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Steve is correct, including the IncludeUserSecurity switch doesn't just query and pull authoring attributes on the list. All users and groups are imported/exported as well. That said, using that switch will also add users to the destination site- a caveat, but slightly expected.

Comment: As I thought, thanks guys. Unfortunately we have 50,000+ users so kind of expected. I may try delete members of the site collection not needed and see if it helps.